# Synonym tags have an "edit" link directing to a "page not found"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

If I hover over a tag on the tags page, an edit link appears. If the tag is a synonym, then following the edit link will result in a "page not found".

[image: edit link]

I would suggest the edit link shouldn't appear for synonyms, should link to some sort of informational page about why synonyms don't have a tag-wiki or in some other way does not result in a "page not found".

Comment: Reproduced on [tag:code-igniter]: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/code-igniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed in latest, thanks for bringing this up